# Insert Vue component into CKEditor 5 editable body

Tags: ckeditor, ckeditor5

TLDR; I want to insert a compiled Vue JS component into the CKEditor editable body, as part of the downcasting process of a plugin.

---

I have a custom CKEditor image plugin, for a CMS-style site. The user inserts an image by selecting their image from an image picker (outside CKEditor), and then a CKEditor command is executed to insert the image:

```
const model = this.editor.model;

model.change(writer => {
  const imageElement = writer.createElement('custom-image');
  const insertAtSelection = findOptimalInsertionPosition(model.document.selection, model);
  model.insertContent(imageElement, insertAtSelection);
});
```

There is a plugin which registers the 'custom-image' element into the schema, inside the plugin's `init` method:

```
const schema = this.editor.model.schema;
schema.register('custom-image', {
  isObject: true,
  isBlock: true,
  allowIn: '$root'
});
```

Then, there is a downcast handler registered (also inside the plugin's `init` method):

```
const conversion = this.editor.conversion;
// A similar handler is used for editingDowncast
conversion.for('dataDowncast').elementToElement({
  model: 'custom-image',
  view: (modelElement, viewWriter) => {
    return writer.createContainerElement('div', {
      class: 'custom-image',
    });
  }
});
```

Now, I have a Vue component, with a reference to the DOM node I would like to insert inside the newly created `div.custom-image` (`ContainerElement`).

I've tried creating a handler on the downcastDispatcher, like so:

```
this.editor.editing.downcastDispatcher.on("insert:custom-image", (evt, data, conversionApi) => {
  const el = ... // Vue component is created here
  const viewElement = conversionApi.mapper.toViewElement(data.item);
  const domNode = view.domConverter.mapViewToDom(viewElement);
  domNode.appendChild(el);
});
```

The problem is 1) `viewElement` doesn't seem to have been added to the DOM yet (so `mapViewToDom` returns undefined), and 2) if I wait for `viewElement` to be added to the DOM (using setTimeout, a nasty hack), the contents of the Vue component are mostly stripped, because the schema doesn't allow for them.

The Vue component that is being added is quite complex, and talks to the application outside CKEditor. Recreating the component using CKEditor's model would be quite messy. It is also used in the view-side of the application, so it would be nice to be able to reuse the same component as part of the editing and viewing part of the app.

So, what would be the best way to solve this issue?

Answer (score 1):

In short - CKEditor5 was designed to prevent this.

> CKEditor 5 implements a custom data model. In order to load data to this model you need to have view -> model converters for each piece
>   of the content that you want your editor to support. Then, you need
>   model -> view converters in order to make this content editable (it
>   needs to be rendered in the editor for editing). Finally, you need to
>   configure the schema and sometimes customize certain features like
>   Enter so they know the meaning of this content that you loaded into
>   the editor and how to modify it.
>
> In other words, because of the data model a feature needs to implement the full life-cycle of a specific piece of content (tag,
>   attribute, etc.) which it handles – from data loading, through
>   rendering for editing, editing itself and data retrieval.

via https://github.com/ckeditor/ckeditor5/issues/705
via https://stackoverflow.com/a/47775840/1225741

I've got a similar use case but with React. In my case I create a custom iframe element to show charts rendered by my webapp but it's not viable in the long run, given that the editor may have dozens of charts loaded. It gets heavy and unusable quite fast.

Currently I'm investigating Web Components as a possible solution for this limitation. AFAIK it Should Work™ but I yet have to code a demo up to confirm this approach.

Did you find a way to solve your issue Michael?

Comment: I actually found a rather non-hackish way to do this. CKEditor 5 has a view Element subclass called UIElement, which is designed for displaying non-editable UI inside the editor. It has a render function which can be used to attach the Vue (or React) DOM element to the DOM element of the UIElement. As long as the Vue/React component you're inserting is read only, it works well. It gets a bit tricker trying to have editable elements inside the Vue/React component (input, textarea etc), but it's doable.

Comment: Awesome, thanks for a fast reply :). It sounds like a far better solution than what we considered. As for editability it will suffice if onClick will work in it (which it should I think).