# Adding Plugins to a Custom Build of CKEditor5 with ReactJS

Tags: reactjs, ckeditor, ckeditor5

I am trying to add a plugin to the classic build of CKEditor5.  I have followed the instructions on this page:  https://ckeditor.com/docs/ckeditor5/latest/installation/plugins/installing-plugins.html

I can tell that I've done everything properly since everything works as it is supposed to when I open up the `sample/index.html`.

Now comes the time to integrate this custom build with my react app.

The instructions on [this page](https://ckeditor.com/docs/ckeditor5/latest/builds/guides/integration/frameworks/react.html), 'describe' what to do:

> You will create a new build somewhere next to your project and include
> it like you included one of the existing builds.

It says to 'include it like you included of one of the existing builds'.  Well, this is how I included the classic-build:

```
import React from "react";
import ReactDOM from "react-dom";
import CKEditor from "@ckeditor/ckeditor5-react";
import ClassicEditor from "@ckeditor/ckeditor5-build-classic";

import "./styles.css";

function App() {
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <CKEditor
        editor={ClassicEditor}
        // Other Props
        }}
      />
    </div>
  );
}

const rootElement = document.getElementById("root");
ReactDOM.render(<App />, rootElement);
```

So, I would assume that I would do something like this:

```
import React from "react";
import ReactDOM from "react-dom";
import CKEditor from "@ckeditor/ckeditor5-react";
import ClassicEditor from './ckeditor/ckeditor'


import "./styles.css";

function App() {
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <CKEditor
        editor={ClassicEditor}
        // Other Props
      />
    </div>
  );
}

const rootElement = document.getElementById("root");
ReactDOM.render(<App />, rootElement);
```

That is, simply change the `import` statement from:

```
import ClassicEditor from "@ckeditor/ckeditor5-build-classic";
```

to

```
import ClassicEditor from './ckeditor/ckeditor'
```

With `./ckeditor/ckeditor/` being the `ckeditor.js` file found in the `build` folder of my modified version of the custom build.

But, this does not work.  There is no export in the new ckeditor.js file.  Neither a default export nor a named export.  So perhaps I should import the file like this:

```
import './ckeditor/ckeditor'
```

But then how do I tell the React component which editor to use.  There is an `editor` prop, which takes the name of the editor to use -- namely:

```
<CKEditor
  editor={ClassicEditor}
  // Other Props
/>
```

So I am stuck.  I have no idea how to include the custom build into my react app.

Any ideas?

Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

The CKEditor team helped me solve this problem.  You can read the solution here:  https://github.com/ckeditor/ckeditor5/issues/2072#issuecomment-534987536

The main point was that I needed to publish my customized build as an npm package, install that package on my site and then import the installed package.

Once I did that, everything worked just fine.

Comment: If this is the only viable option to allow me to add a simple button with onClick callback.
I should look for an alternative. Because mundane features like these should not require over-complicated solutions like this.

Comment: If it's a dependency free plugin you could use the `extraPlugin` interface and avoid rebuilding a custom editor.

https://ckeditor.com/docs/ckeditor5/latest/builds/guides/integration/configuration.html#adding-features

Answer (score 1):

**Forget what you know about customizing cke4 then read this**

---

*Steps to customize your CK5 Editor*

- fork the [ckeditor5 classic build](https://github.com/ckeditor/ckeditor5-build-classic)
- clone your new fork
- customize the ckeditor (I used the [online build tool](https://ckeditor.com/ckeditor-5/online-builder/))
- build the editor with `$ npm build`
- add & commit changes
- push your commits to your forked repo
- clone your forked repo to your existing project and use the ckeditor from YOUR build.

This process is not very straight forward and the documentation on it is non-existent at best. Hopefully my pain is your gain!

*Extra*

The online build tool has you download a .zip and what I did was overwrote my forked project files with the ones form the zip. I built, uploaded, etc. Make note that the config for the toolbar is inside the sample/index.html if you don't add that then you won't see your toolbar.

**Remember to add the toolbar config!**

** EDIT **

*If you're working on a team you'll want to go with the version at the top.*

## Simpler

- Use the [Online Build Tool](https://ckeditor.com/ckeditor-5/online-builder/)
- download the zip to your project
- go to the folder in git and `npm install`
- edit your `ckeditor.js` to include the config from `sample/index.html` (I put everything in my `Editor.defaultConfig`)
- in the same folder run `npm build`
- go to your main project and import ckeditor from the build you just made eg `import ClassicEditor from './online-build/build/ckeditor';`
- in the project folder run `npm build`

If everything works except you don't have a toolbar then you need to re-examine your config setup.

Cheers!

** EDIT **

I wanted to add the "source editing" plugin which doesn't seem supported (??) What I did was manually snagged the [source-editing code](https://github.com/ckeditor/ckeditor5/tree/master/packages/ckeditor5-source-editing) from the [ckeditor5 main git](https://github.com/ckeditor/ckeditor5) (all the plugins are listed at the bottom) then pasted that code into my project and imported from that folder. This is all a bit chaotic and it's not suitable for teams BUT IT WORKS - good luck

```
import SourceEditing from './ckeditor5-source-editing/src/sourceediting.js';
```